# JQuery AJAX call returns: OK

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The ajax response is: OK.  Here is the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        alert('Test');


        $('#div1 h2').text('Test');
        var divToBeWorkedOn = "#div1";
        var n1 = 1;
        var n2 = 2;
        var webMethod = "AJAXTest.html";
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: webMethod,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(result.text);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(e.statusText);
            }
        });



    })
});
</script>
```

AJAXTest.html contains the following Text: Test.  Therefore I expect the div1 content to change to: Test.  However, it changes to: OK.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show youy AjaxText.html page?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, thanks.  It just contains the word: Test.  That is it.

Comment: have you tried like this:``$(divToBeWorkedOn).html(result);``

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: For future reference @w0051977, you should debug the callbacks to see what's being hit, and what's being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change datatype `json` to `html`.

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'webMethod',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            jQuery("#div_id").html(result);
        },
        error: function (e) { }
    });
```

try it,

Comment: Yep, to expand on this.  It's hitting error, not success due to a JSON parsing error.  So you're setting the div to `statusText` and not the returned result.